# O RSelenium parou de funcionar, o que devo fazer?

Tags: r

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'firefox')
remDrv$open()**texto em negrito**

Selenium message:The path to the driver executable must be set by the     
webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be 
downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Comment: Você atualizou a biblioteca? Qual a versão dela?

Comment: Atualizada... Baixei agora novamente!

Comment: Documentation for package ‘RSelenium’ version 1.4.8 @StillBuggin

Answer (score 0):

P'ra mim, deu tudo certo.

Meus passos:

1. `install.packages('RSelenium')`;
2. `RSelenium::checkForServer()` (espera terminar a execução);
3. `RSelenium::startServer()`
4. `require(RSelenium)`
5. `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'firefox')`
6. `remDr`

Output:

```html
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4444

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$autoClose
[1] FALSE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()
```

Comment: Ainda assim não abre o navegador

Comment: > remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method